# Get id of current inserted item by javascript. Could you please help me some one what is I am doing wrong below code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

```
// Adding record into list

function createListItem() {
    var rows = document.getElementById('tblPets').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    alert(rows);
    var i;
    var fdata;
    for(i=1; i<rows; i++) {
        alert("test");
        if (fdata == null) {
            var fdata = document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;
        }
        else {
            var fdata = fdata + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;
        }
        fdata = fdata + "," + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;
        fdata = fdata + "," + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
        fdata = fdata + "," + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[3].children[0].value;
        fdata = fdata + "," + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[4].children[0].value;
        fdata = fdata + "," + document.getElementById('tblPets').rows[i].cells[5].children[0].value+";";
        alert(fdata);
    }

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var obList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Family Visa Requests');
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var obListItem = obList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    if(document.getElementById('chkPermanent').checked == true) 
        obListItem.set_item('VisaType', 'permanent');  
    else 
        obListItem.set_item('VisaType', 'Visit');

    obListItem.set_item('BadgeNumber', document.getElementById('txtbnumber').value);
    //alert('Badge number added');
    obListItem.set_item('CostCenter', document.getElementById('txtccenter').value);
    //alert('CostCenter added');
    obListItem.set_item('EmployeeName', document.getElementById('txtename').value);
    //alert('EmployeeName added');
    var currDate = new Date();
    obListItem.set_item('AppliedDate', currDate);
    //alert('AppliedDate added');
    obListItem.set_item('Position', document.getElementById('txtposition').value);
    //alert('Position added');
    obListItem.set_item('Section', document.getElementById('txtsection').value);
    //alert('Section added');
    obListItem.set_item('Department', document.getElementById('txtdepartment').value);
    //alert('Department added');
    obListItem.set_item('Nationality', document.getElementById('txtnationality').value);
    //alert('Nationality added');
    obListItem.set_item('Location', document.getElementById('txtlocation').value);
    //alert('Location added');
    obListItem.set_item('PhoneNumber', document.getElementById('txtpnumber').value);
    //alert('PhoneNumber added');

    var e = document.getElementById("jstatus");
    //alert(e);

    var jobstatus = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;       
    //alert(jjstatus);
    obListItem.set_item('JobStatus', jobstatus);
   // alert('JobStatus added');
    var n = document.getElementById("Cname");
    var compname = n.options[n.selectedIndex].text;
    obListItem.set_item('CompanyName', compname);
    //alert('CompanyName added'); 
    //Educational Back ground
    obListItem.set_item('HighestEducationalAttainment', document.getElementById('DEducation').value);
    obListItem.set_item('NameOfSchoolUniversity', document.getElementById('NUniversity').value);
    obListItem.set_item('NumberOfYearsAttended', document.getElementById('NYears').value);
    // oListItem.set_item('DateGraduated', document.getElementById('DGraduated').value);
    alert(rows - 1);
    obListItem.set_item('DependentCount', rows - 1);
    obListItem.set_item('FamilyData', fdata);         
    obListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(obListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryitemcreateSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryitemcreateFailed));

}



function onQueryitemcreateSucceeded() {
    alert("Item Created");

    alert('Item created: ' + obListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryitemcreateFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps related to Scope of `obListItem`. Try changing   `var obListItem = obList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);` to `this.obListItem = obList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);`. Or define `obListItem` outside of `function createListItem()`